# Firebase inactive user removal from database list

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

This is my Firebase database structure:

```
// Registered users
users{
  9BKlHH11NvU1kQdpwSaFshNJn8C2{
    foo: foo
    bar: bar
  B5Lq9RquOvcK7CLhh1Mdq0qWCqO2{
    foo: foo
    bar: bar

// Connected users inside the lobby
Lobby{
  9BKlHH11NvU1kQdpwSaFshNJn8C2,
  B5Lq9RquOvcK7CLhh1Mdq0qWCqO2
```

So everytime a registered user logs in and enters the lobby, his uid is added to the lobby list so everybody sees him. If he logs out there's a process to remove him from the lobby list.
Now the problem is; what would be the best approach to remove a user that has closed the browser/app without leaving the lobby so the rest of the users don't see someone that is not actually connected in that list? Is there a timeout function maybe?

Comment: OnDisconnect will handle that! Here's the iOS function [Firebase API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/ios/firebasedatabase/api/reference/Classes/FIRDatabaseReference#/c:objc(cs)FIRDatabaseReference(im)onDisconnectSetValue:)

Comment: Is there a cordova plugin for that? I'm using Ionic 2 and I haven't found anything related.

Answer (score 0):

There is no timeout function.

Though on the application end, you can add and check the entry in Lobby, and send the beacon request in every 10 or 30 sec or more to make the entry in lobby valid.

And in the UI, while listing Users in the Lobby, if Lobby entry is older than the beacon time, you can either not list them or send a request to remove them.

It will be better to just skip the addition of that User in the UI, let the old entries be there. Sending the removal request will be contradicting, and will arise conflicts if more front ends are sending request to remove same User from Lobby. But, its all up to your app structure and Use Case.

Comment: I've already implemented logic checks that remove users in different ways. The problem is checking for a uid in a database list. Is there maybe a way to check if a uid is online without using the database? For example, a user clicks on a name in the lobby list and the process looks if that user is online without relying on a database list. That way, I could implement users deleting offline uids.